# Is it possible to record the audio output with flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, audio-recording

I want to build an audio recorder with flutter but I cannot seem to find any way to record the audio played from the device rather than the microphone itself. Is there any way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_audio_recorder

https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

These two packages are useful to achieve audio recoding and playing in flutter.

Here's some code reference-

```
  bool isRecordingStarted = false;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  FlutterAudioRecorder _recorder;
  Recording _recording;
  Timer _t;
  var recordedAudio;
  RecordingStatus _currentStatus = RecordingStatus.Unset;
  IconData _recordIcon = Icons.mic_none;
  Duration _duration;
  Duration _position;

  Future _startRecording() async {
    await _recorder.start();
    var current = await _recorder.current();
    setState(() {
      _recording = current;
    });

    _t = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (Timer t) async {
      var current = await _recorder.current();
      setState(() {
        _recording = current;
        _t = t;
      });
    });
  }

  Future _stopRecording() async {
    var result = await _recorder.stop();
    _t.cancel();

    setState(() {
      // _recording = result;
      _recording = new Recording();
    });
    print("_recording.path : ${result.path}");
    setState(() {
      recordedAudio = result.path;
    });
    // Navigator.pushNamed(context, Screen.AudioPostingView.toString(),
    //     arguments: {"audioUrl": result.path});
  }
```

///For Audio playing

```
 playLocal() async {
    int result = await advancedPlayer.play(recordedAudio, isLocal: true);
    // setState(() => playerState = PlayerState.playing);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // getLastPost();
    _init();
    _loadRiveFile();
    _prepare();
    _getDuration();
    // startTimer();

    advancedPlayer.onDurationChanged
        .listen((d) => setState(() => _duration = d));
    // _initAudioPlayer();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: does this really record the device audio, rather than the microphone audio?